# I can't get flash plugin to work on Centos 6.6

Tags: centos, repository, adobe-flash

I keep getting error:plug in needed to view content when ever I want to watch certain videos on certain sites... this was just a matter of installing flash-plug in on my fedora 22 laptop. But when I try to install it on my Centos 6.6 laptop I'm getting this in the terminal :

```
[root@horriblehost /]# yum install flash plug-in
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit, security
Setting up Install Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos.aol.com
 * extras: mirrors.sonic.net
 * rpmforge: mirror.chpc.utah.edu
 * updates: centos.mirror.constant.com
http://linux.dropbox.com/fedora/6/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found"
Trying other mirror.
Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: Dropbox. Please verify its path and try again
[root@horriblehost /]#
```

I'm not sure why references to dropbox keep popping up. My dropbox is working... Any help? I would really like to get flash working. I'm new to this Linux thing ( but loving it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you configured your `CentOS 6.6` to use a repository that contains `flash-plugin`, [RepoForge](http://repoforge.org/use/) for example?

The `dropbox` error occurs because `http://linux.dropbox.com/fedora/6/repodata/repomd.xml` does not exist.  `CentOS` is not listed at `http://linux.dropbox.com`.  You can disable the repository temporarily with:

```
yum install flash-plugin --disablerepo=Dropbox
```

or make it persistent by setting:

```
enabled=0
```

in `/etc/yum.repos.d/Dropbox.repo` or whatever the `dropbox` repo file is named.

**EDIT:**

Please note that `Flash` is unsupported on `Linux`.  [This link](http://www.howtogeek.com/193876/using-firefox-on-linux-your-flash-player-is-old-and-outdated/) provides more information.

As requested, here are some informational links about repositories and YUM:

[Adding a repository](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/rhel5-fedora-core-add-new-yum-repository.html)

[Setup and Use repositories](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-and-use-yum-repositories-on-a-centos-6-vps)

[YUM HowTo](http://www.phy.duke.edu/~rgb/General/yum_HOWTO/yum_HOWTO/)

Comment: This worked for installing flash-plugin! The --disablerepo=Dropbox worked like a charm. I will disable the repo for good next. Thank you. I'm still not sure how the repo thing works, suggestions for reading? I tried to up vote your answer but I guess I don't have much of a reputation around here, lol...

Answer (score 0):

In the syntax of the command you have written, yum is attempting to install two packages: flash and plug-in.

You got the name wrong. Try `yum install flash-plugin`.

NOTE: Alternatively, you can install Adobe Flash player manually from their website, untar the file, copy `libflashplayer.so` to `~/.mozilla/plugins`, and copy all of the files provided in `usr` (from the untar'd flash player file) to `/usr` using `cp usr/* /usr`.

Comment: when I try copying /usr* to /usr it says 'omitting' to every file it tries to copy ( there are three in there)